# search from different table php

Tags: php, mysql

This is the part of my webpage.

[image]

I am displaying students fees details with student name in that page. I have a search section using student name as a keyword. The details are fetched from the fees table and students name s are saved as ids in the fees table. The students names are kept in an another table named tbl_students. I have used the following query to search.

```
$search = $_REQUEST['Submit'];
    $keyword = $_REQUEST['keyword'];


    if($keyword != ''  )
    $fn = " and varStudentName LIKE '%$keyword%' ";

$mainarr['query'] = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_students` where 1=1 ".$fn."  order by intstudentId  DESC";
```

The search works fine i.e searched students name displayed but the other details like reason and amount are not displayed. I think it's because they are in the fees table.

I need all the details should display when i search using the student name. How can i do that?

Comment: You need to join students and fees table, then select from that join....

Comment: "where 1=1" where does 1 not equal 1 ?

Comment: @dagon looks like it's just there so that $fn can stick an "and" at the beginning without having to check whether there are other terms in the WHERE clause already. Currently there's only ever one, but it looks like this code may have been copied from a more detailed script that could pile on multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In short you are right your query is on a different table to the data you are trying to display. The best thing to do here would probably be a SQL Join statement. The documentation here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp explains the exact same join statement you are trying to do with the context of customers and orders instead of students and fees.

Answer (score 0):

Join the student and fees table using student_id

```
 $keyword= mysql_real_escape_string($_post['keyword'])
 select * from student st
 inner join fees f on st.studentId =f.studentId
 where st.studentname like '%keyword%'
 order by studentId desc  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough information about the other tables for anyone to suggest a proper left join, but, otherwise **PLEASE** make sure to sanitize your query.

This is bad: `$keyword = $_REQUEST['keyword'];`

Reason why it's bad is because someone could type this in their browser:

`http://yourwebpage/?keyword=%';+drop+table+tbl_students`

And by doing so, they can delete all of your data.

As you can see, that's likely an open vulnerability as it appears to allow remote visitors complete access over your MySQL server. For safety reasons, you need to sanitize your input.  For example, like this:

`$keyword = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['keyword']);`

or

`$keyword = mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['keyword'];)`

Do that before issuing your mysql_query(). Even if your magic quotes setting is on, if anyone migrates this code over to another server, that safety net won't be there.